# Witcher 3 -- Possession quest ending

Tags: the-witcher-3

I'm a little confused about one of the possible conclusions of the side quest "Possession":

> In the "Trick" ending, Cerys gives Geralt a the baby, and tells him to put the baby in the oven.  If the player obeys Cerys, Geralt puts the baby in the oven(!) and slams the oven door shut, then puts a Quen barrier around it.  It's later revealed that the baby is completely unharmed, and in the adjacent room.

My question is, how is that ending possible?

> Geralt is the one who started the fire, and had to truly believe that he killed the baby in order for the trick to work.  How did the baby get from the oven, to the adjacent room?  How did the other character (a priest, I believe; I don't remember his name) arrive in the house, get to the adjacent room, and retrieve the baby while everyone was fighting *and* a Quen barrier was around the oven?

I expected that Cerys would explain things afterward, but I didn't have any option to discuss it with her.  Is this explained or hinted at elsewhere in the game?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you take your time to explore the house before hand (as I did even before getting the quest and it scared the shit out of me with the sounds it made) you could find a room behind the oven.

If you go into this room behind the oven you can see it has an opening on that side too. The old dude (whose Name is [Hjort](http://witcher.wikia.com/wiki/Hjort) :) ) who walks out with the baby was waiting in that room and knew Cerys plan. Therefore tricking Geralt into thinking he was responsible for killing the baby tricking the Hym.

Comment: Thanks, I explored the house, but Cerys interrupted me before I got to that room.  If you examine that room *before* attempting the trick, does it make the trick fail (since Geralt would know about the other opening)?

Comment: Nope it does not because it did not affect me. I explored the house inside and out before doing the mission and it didn't affect the outcome

Comment: @liesmith no because Geralt still didn't know that Hjort was there.  As far as he knew it was just him and Cerys so the baby got burned.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and thorough answers; I thought I must've missed something subtle about Hjort in particular.